# Git tries to fetch Null commit when pushing

Tags: git

I have cloned a github repository into another bare repository using the `--bare` option. But when I push a commit to this repository I get this output:

```
Fetching remote heads...
  refs/
  refs/tags/
  refs/heads/
  refs/remotes/
  refs/remotes/origin/
  fetch 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
Unable to fetch 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, will not be able to update server info refs
updating 'refs/heads/master'
  from db82a9e0b834b59922b42ff193984f7cbc4fb295
  to   b694385d28056e9182314f770b1380a424f49bfa
    sending 4 objects
    done
Unable to update server info
To http://www/git/asi-http-request.git
   db82a9e..b694385  master -> master
```

I'm using DAV transport and therefore the post-update hook which only contains `git update-server-info` is not executed making the last commit invisible. I have to manually run the `update-server-info` command

I noticed that the `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` file contains a symbolic reference to `refs/remotes/origin/master` which does not exist. I tried to create containing the commit reference of the master branch in the origin repository but I'm still facing the same error when pushing new commits.

git version is 1.7.2.5

Does anyone has an idea of what is going on and how I can fix it?

**EDIT 01 Feb. 2013**

The `git log HEAD` command on the remote repository returns that output (I removed author commit message):

```
commit b694385d28056e9182314f770b1380a424f49bfa
Author: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Date:   Tue Jan 29 18:44:05 2013 +0100

    ...

commit db82a9e0b834b59922b42ff193984f7cbc4fb295
Author: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Date:   Tue Jan 29 10:59:59 2013 +0100

    ...

commit 6300b759329d5d5d715d0fc76d15424c12a87bd4
Author: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Date:   Sat Jan 5 13:28:27 2013 +0100

    ...
```

I'm not sure this is relevant since I ran `git update-server-info`.

Comment: what is the output of `git log HEAD` when run in the remote repo?

Comment: I updated the question with the log output

Comment: mhh, that doesn’t really help :/. Can you use another transport protocol (ssh or http)? There is no need to use DAV in the current git version, as git has full http support now.

Answer (score 0):

I would try not cloning the repo into a `--bare` one:

- `cd your_bare`
- `git clone --bare git@github.com...`

but instead **cloning it into a normal one first**

create your bare repo

- `cd your_bare`
- `git init --bare`

now clone the repo

- `cd /tmp`
- `git clone git@github.com...`
- `cd repo`
- `git remote rename origin upstream`

and push it to your bare repo

- `git remote add origin your_bare`
- `git push origin master`